# calculate the unique entries and bindrows column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to find the unique entries for ID1 and ID2 so if a "aaf" entered the data in id1 and id2 the if will be single entry so here unique entries will 8 from id1 and id2 . i want to assing unique entries in separate variable . you can refer the pic below

then i want to bind the columns one by another like the pic below. final db should be look like binding rows

```
df <- structure(list(city=c("del","mum","nav","pun","bang","chen","triv","vish","del"),
                      name= c("xab","Lan","mun","mmc","aaf","nnhu","njam","jiha","ntha"),
  `ID 1` = c(653, NA, 240, NA, 826, NA, NA, 440, 
 385), `ID 2` = c(NA, 610, NA, 240, 551, 854, NA, 490, 653),
 `S1`=c(213, 233, NA, NA, 333, 543, 122, NA, 765),
`S1`=c(176, NA, NA, 100, 124, 621, NA, 434, 323)), row.names = c(NA, 
      -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

calculation of unique entries like below
[image]

bind the column like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there may be a better way you can achieve your ultimate goal with the data here, but without further information I can only provide a literal answer to your post. This chunk solves for the first part of your question:

```
require(tidyverse) 

df %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(ID_distinct = n_distinct(c_across(`ID 1`:`ID 2`), na.rm = TRUE),
           S_distinct = n_distinct(c_across(S1:S2), na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
    relocate(ID_distinct, .after = `ID 2`)

# A tibble: 9 × 8
# Rowwise: 
  city  name  `ID 1` `ID 2` ID_distinct    S1    S2 S_distinct
  <chr> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>       <int> <dbl> <dbl>      <int>
1 del   xab      653     NA           1   213   176          2
2 mum   Lan       NA    610           1   233    NA          1
3 nav   mun      240     NA           1    NA    NA          0
4 pun   mmc       NA    240           1    NA   100          1
5 bang  aaf      826    551           2   333   124          2
6 chen  nnhu      NA    854           1   543   621          2
7 triv  njam      NA     NA           0   122    NA          1
8 vish  jiha     440    490           2    NA   434          1
9 del   ntha     385    653           2   765   323          2
```

And this chunk solves for the second part:

```
stack(df[3:4]) %>% 
    bind_cols(
        stack(df[5:6])
    ) %>%
    rename(ID1 = `values...1`, S1 = `values...3`) %>%
    select(-c(`ind...2`, `ind...4`)) %>%
    as_tibble()



New names:
* values -> values...1
* ind -> ind...2
* values -> values...3
* ind -> ind...4
# A tibble: 18 × 2
     ID1    S1
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1   653   213
 2    NA   233
 3   240    NA
 4    NA    NA
 5   826   333
 6    NA   543
 7    NA   122
 8   440    NA
 9   385   765
10    NA   176
11   610    NA
12    NA    NA
13   240   100
14   551   124
15   854   621
16    NA    NA
17   490   434
18   653   323
```

If you can provide more context about what you're hoping to achieve with your data, I (or someone else) can possibly offer better instruction.